# What is the difference between <>() and <DataType>() in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

What is the difference between `ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<>()` and `ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>()`? I'm confused.

Comment: The first one is shorter, since the type can be automatically inferred.

Answer (score 3):

Both are actually the same.
When generics were introduced in Java 5, we had to use

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When Java 7 arrived, one of the featured it delivered was the support of the shorter form:

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<>();
```

So if you're on Java 7+ you can use both (of course the shorter form is preferred)

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference , if you use java 1.6 or older versions you should write your code like this

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but after java 1.6 it will infer the type and you can write your code with just a diamond `<>`.

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<>();
```